# Get the sum of the value of a variable in a PHP while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

This will display all the product selections a user has made and it works. I need to add a variable with a function that will return the sum for all instances of $total_price so I can display a total price of all products (items) selected. I'm sure it will be a simple matter for many of you. 
I do not know how to do it and have been unable to find an example. This code is from the shopping cart and I can just use it as part of checkout as long as I can show the total price of all selections. 
It should be a simple matter to take that subtotal and add tax after that. 
Will someone please show me the code for the $sub_total?

```
<?php
session_start();
//connect to database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hestonw0355");
//$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "hestonw0355", "1Password!", "hestonw0355"); //for the school server
//$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sungr_RobW", "O+N7?Pa%Go*T&", "sungraff_hestonw0355") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli)); //for dailyrazor.com

$display_block = "<h1>Your Shopping Cart</h1>";

//check for cart items based on user session id
$get_cart_sql = "SELECT st.id, si.item_title, si.item_price,
                st.sel_item_qty, st.sel_item_size, st.sel_item_color FROM
                store_shoppertrack AS st LEFT JOIN store_items AS si ON
                si.id = st.sel_item_id WHERE session_id =
                '".$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']."'";
$get_cart_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_cart_sql)
                or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

if (mysqli_num_rows($get_cart_res) < 1) {
    //print message
    $display_block .= "<p>You have no items in your cart.
    Please <a href=\"seestore.php\">continue to shop</a>!</p>";
} else {

    while ($cart_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_cart_res)) {
        $id = $cart_info['id'];
        $item_title = stripslashes($cart_info['item_title']);
        $item_price = $cart_info['item_price'];
        $item_qty = $cart_info['sel_item_qty'];
        $item_color = $cart_info['sel_item_color'];
        $item_size = $cart_info['sel_item_size'];
        $total_price = sprintf("%.02f", $item_price * $item_qty);
        $sub_total = 

    //get info and build cart display
    $display_block .= <<<END_OF_TEXT

    <table width='100%'>
    <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Total Price</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>$item_title <br></td>
    <td>$item_size <br></td>
    <td>$item_color <br></td>
    <td>\$ $item_price <br></td>
    <td>$item_qty <br></td>
    <td>\$ $total_price</td>
    <td><a href="removefromcart.php?id=$id">remove</a></td>
    </tr>
END_OF_TEXT;
    }
    $display_block .= "</table>";
}
//free result
mysqli_free_result($get_cart_res);

//close connection to MySQL
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $display_block; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a horrible code style. Consider to separate logic from the mark upü. Separate html,  php, js, mysql etc

Comment: Please remove your passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the global total price you can:

set a variable `$sub_total` before the `while` as follow:

```
$sub_total = 0;
```

In the `while` loop you add to your variable the `$total_price` calculated for each iteration as follow:

```
$sub_total = $sub_total + $total_price
```

or in compact way:

```
$sub_total += $total_price
```

An advice:

change this:

```
$total_price = sprintf("%.02f", $item_price * $item_qty);
```

in:

```
$total_price = $item_price * $item_qty;
```

and format your value when you want to display.

Other code parts shoud be changed, but I focalized my attention on your main request.

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
$sub_total = 0 before while loop starts;
```

Then do `$sub_total += $total_price`.In the end of while loop $sub_total will contain total price of all the products.

Comment: It works great! ($sub_total = 0;) and ($sub_total += $total_price;) then I put in: <tr>
 <td colspan='5'></td>
 <td style='text-align: right;'>Subtotal: </td>
 <td>\$ $sub_total </td>
 </tr>

Comment: It works great! ($sub_total = 0;) and ($sub_total += $total_price;) then I put in: <tr>
 <td colspan='5'></td>
 <td style='text-align: right;'>Subtotal: </td>
 <td>\$ $sub_total </td>
 </tr>    ....and each box for an item that's displayed has the subtotal up to that point. Maybe the totals should display and change in a different area of the page, but this is great just the way it is. I'll put in the tax the same way. Should be like ($grandtotal = sprintf("%.02f", $sub_total * .06 + $sub_total)